# How to make relation in neo4j from python matrix fast?

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a cosine similarity matrix in python and i want to make a relation based on that value.
My query is

`MATCH (n:Product {id : {id}}),(m:Product {id:{id2}})
 MERGE (n)-[r:SIM]-(m)
 SET r.weight={w}`

and i'm insert the relation by doing this

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(x):
        make_relation(i,j,w)
```

Is there a faster method to insert relation than the nested loop because it took times too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping and executing, use your loop to populate a list, so we can use the trick of UNWINDING the list and executing for all list entries in a single operation.

Let one of your parameters to your cypher query be a list of dictionaries (let's call it 'rowList' as the key in the parameter map), with the list pre-populated by your double-for loop for `id` and `id2` and `w`.

Your Cypher can be a similar query as in your description, but we can change it to use your passed in list. You'll unwind the list into rows, and create the relationships all at once. This becomes a single operation rather than one per pair.

```
UNWIND {rowList} as row
MATCH (n:Product {id : {row.id}}),(m:Product {id:{row.id2}})
MERGE (n)-[r:SIM]-(m)
SET r.weight={row.w}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its give me the alternative method though. After creating the list, i write it in csv. Then, using periodic commit, i load the csv and make relation using the query above in a single cypher